# Compilation Issue on Jquery in React JS

Tags: jquery, node.js, reactjs

In My React Application Jquery-min.js file is not working ,its showing the error that attached below, please help me find out solution my problem?

[jquery-min.js error msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pX7fm.png)

I tried of re-installing jquery many times with different jquery versions, but it is showing same error like i attached in the image and i also tried using different node versions and vs code versions , it's not working